# Unique Validator de Laravel no funciona en update

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando actualizar usuarios de una lista que obtengo mediante una consulta a la base de datos, pero al hacerlo me envía un mensaje de error diciendo que **El campo email ya está en uso**. Pero está en uso por el usuario que estoy intentando actualizar, no por otro.

Tengo lo siguiente en UserController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
$args = [
    'name'          => 'required|min:8',
    'email'         => ['required', new FilterEmail, Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id)],
    'role'          => 'required',
    'description'   => 'required',
    'active'        => 'boolean',
    'pseg'          => 'boolean',
];
$data = Validator::make( $request->all(), $args );
...
}
```

El problema está dado en esta linea:

```
'email' => ['required', new FilterEmail, Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id)],
```

Estoy fijándome cómo lo muestra en la documentación oficial de Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) pero siempre me lanza el mismo error.

¿Alguna idea de qué es lo que está sucediendo? Gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 1):

*prueba esto*

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
  $this->validate(request(), ['required', new FilterEmail, Rule::unique('users')
  ->ignore($id, 'id')]);
}
```

*no olvide importar* `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule`
 si no usa `id` *, cámbielo por su id personalizado de la tabla users*

Comment: Entre tantas cosas que he intentado, esta ha sido una de ellas. Realmente no sé qué pueda estar pasando...

Comment: Estaba utilizando (mal) cookies para recuperar mensajes de error, pero he cambiado a usar sessions (entre otras cosas) y todo va bien. El error no estaba dado por la validación, sino por mal uso de otros elementos. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que a mi me ha funcionado:

'campo_a_validar' => 'unique:nombre_tabla, campo en tabla,'. $id que tiene,
el $id es el mismo que pasas en el metodo update.

'email' => 'unique:cat_users,email,' . $id,